# How to apply theme in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing fragments tabs,in that I want to develop tabs and page indicators.  For this purpose I am using Jack Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator project, but the tabs showing normal view no indicator is getting. I am not unable to applying theme as android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults in manifest file how can i applying theme.

How i can apply this theme for fragments in mnanifest file. ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.del"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.del.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.del.MainActivity2" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.del.MainActivity3" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.del.MainActivity1" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I am developing fragments tabs,in that I want to develop tabs and page indicators. For this purpose I am using Jack Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator project, but the tabs showing normal view no indicator is getting. I am not unable to applying theme as android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults in manifest file how can i applying theme.

How can applying this themefor framents in mnanifestfile. ?

Answer (score 2):

set

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults" >
```

instead of:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Bye. ;)